# Update of elasticsearch plugin

Tags: plugins, elasticsearch, updates

I have developed a couple of plugins for elasticsearch, and these may require (more or less) frequent updates.
My simple question is: is there a way of updating an elasticsearch plugin without having to remove the old version, delete the relevant indexes, install the new version and rebuild the indexes from scratch?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to update an existing plugin. You need to delete the old version and install the new one.

I didn't get your question about indices though. A plugin doesn't necessarily work against data, it can just be a site plugin, a query parser etc. In case a plugin does work against indices and you want to upgrade it, but the elasticsearch version stays the same, I don't see why you would need to reindex. The only case is if the plugin itself changed in a non backwards compatible way.

Answer (score 0):

As of the latest version 2.4.1 (2016-10-18) there is still no way to do this easily, because the elasticsearch folks [recommend manual plugin updates](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/15000).

Expect that when you update Elasticsearch and start the service, that you will end up with an error because service won't start due to a plugin being one minor version behind the ES version, e.g. "license".

Go to your elasticsearch bin directory and run the following commands:

```
sudo ./plugin remove <plugin name>
sudo ./plugin install <plugin name>
```

You could even be so bold as to write an "update" shell script that does this for you.

Answer (score 0):

A bash script here:

```
#!/bin/bash

plugin_bin=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/plugin
for plugin in $($plugin_bin list | awk '/^\s*-\s*(\S+)/{print $2}')
do
    $plugin_bin remove $plugin && $plugin_bin install $plugin
done
```